# Online application with RESTful webservice design

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-authentication

I am just woundering, how we can use RESTful architecture/webservice to implement online shopping kind of application ?

Say we want to build anything like Amazon where user can login and do shopping. First time, we will perform authentication using HTTP Basic or any other security mechanism, which is fine.

Now, when user made a second request he need to send some authorization code or sessionId or something else so that server will know this is the same user which has logon earlier. But, RESTful webservice is stateless so we are not suppose to store old session related stuff. In that case how we can authenticate user ?

I read something about cliet and server certificates but it is applicable to application where two different services are communicating with each other. Am I correct ?

I am new to webservice :-) so this type of silly question came to my mind.

Comment: [This article](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) on securing web services should help.

Comment: Nice article, I'll read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http basic auth stores the username and password on the client side, and it sends it again with every request. So by REST you have to send these identification factors and authenticate by every request...

You can cache the authentication mechanism if you want it to be faster...

This is an important thing by REST... REST stores the session on client side, not on server side... If you want store something important on server side, then it has to be a resource or a property of a resource...

If you allow somebody to write 3rd party application (another client for your REST service), then the user should accept that this 3rd party application can send requests in his/her name. Ofc. the user does not want to share his/her password, so give permissions to 3rd party applications is a hard stuff. For example oauth solves this problem...

The basic concept by 3rd party applications (clients), that you ask the user whether it allows them to send certain requests or not. For example by facebook it asks, if you want share your identity, list of acquaintances, etc... and you allow to send posts in your behalf, etc... After you clicked ok, the REST application should store that information and give the client permissions to your account. How to check who sends the requests? Ofc. CSRF is not allowed, so the 3rd party client cannot send a cross domain request on your behalf with the client you are using. So it has to send its requests trough a different connection, probably with curl. What should it send? Ofc. the request details. What else? Its identity (an api key) and your identity. This is the most basic approach.

There are other solutions. You can use a similar approach to what you are using by storing passwords in a database. You store only hashes of the passwords hashed with a slow algorithm. By the authentication you create the hash again on the given password. When the stored hash is equal with the newly created, then the application accepts the identity and grants access to the account. You can use the same approach by requests. The 3rd party client requires a hash for a request. After that it sends the request with the hash it got, and by getting the request, the server compares that hash with the hash it creates based on the content of the request. If they are equal, the request is valid. This is cool stuff, because it prevents a CSRF attack on a 3rd party client as well...

I guess there are many other, more complex approaches, I don't know, I am not a security expert and probably you won't be either. You just have to understand the basics and use a tool for example oauth if you want to allow 3rd party access to your api. If you don't want that, then probably you don't need a REST application, just a simple web application... That depends on your needs, visitor count, etc...